# Ruby readline from Arduino occasionally hangs

Tags: ruby, serial-port, arduino

This program reads from the serial port coming from the Arduino (don't think that matters).

Normally everything reads fine, but once in a while the SerialPort gem connects but no data ever gets printed out from `p line`. I expect data to come in every .5s

I would like to detect that no data is coming in and retry the Serial connection.

- `readline` is blocking
- `SerialPort.read_timeout=` doc states does not work well with multi-threading.

Any ideas?

```
#params for serial port 
baud_rate = 115200
data_bits = 8  
stop_bits = 1  
parity    = SerialPort::NONE

tries_cnt = 0
begin
  port_str = [
    "/dev/ttyACM0", # Raspbian
    "/dev/tty.usbmodemfd121",  # OS X
    "/dev/tty.usbmodemfa1311",
  ][tries_cnt]

  @sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity)
  p [self.class.name.demodulize.to_sym, :info, "Connected on #{port_str}"]
rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
  p [self.class.name.demodulize.to_sym, :warning, "No Serial Port for: #{port_str}, trying next."]
  tries_cnt += 1
  retry
rescue TypeError => e
  p [self.class.name.demodulize.to_sym, :error, "Couldn't find any suitable Serial Port. Exiting."]
  exit
end

sleep(5) #Give the port some time to connect. 1s too fast, 2s works, 3s just in case

@read_ser_thread = Thread.new do

  @sp.flush # Clean it out before we go

  while line = @sp.readline
    line = line.strip

    p line        
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Normally everything reads fine, but once in a while the SerialPort gem
>   connects but no data ever gets printed out from p line

readline reads up to and including the value of $/, which by default is "\n".  That means if no "\n" ever appears in the data, readline will hang.

> I would like to detect that no data is coming in

You could have the readline thread write a message to a Queue after readline returns (i.e. on the next line).  Your main thread (or another thread) could then check the Queue for the message.  If no message is in the Queue after .5 secs, then you know the thread is blocking on the readline.